# ¿Como copiar un archivo en lugar de mover?

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación hecha en Java, donde muevo archivos de un directorio a otro y los organiza, el problema esta en que los mueve mas no los copia, otra duda seria, que si este archivo se copia ¿Se modificaran los atributos del archivo, por ejemplo, la fecha de creación?

Lo que necesito saber es como puedo copiarlos en lugar de moverlos, esta es la parte del método donde los muevo usando el `renameTo`.

```
//Si se realizo con exito el movimiento de archivos
if(bool){ 
    bool = false;
    resultNuFolder = NuCarpetaCnFicha(newPath, noFicha);
    bool = finalArchivo.renameTo(new File(resultNuFolder, oldName));
    if(bool)
        bool=true;
} else {
    System.out.println("El archivo "+ oldName + " no pudo ser cambiado de destino");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde version 7:

```
bool resultado = Files.copy( origen, destino, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES );
if (resultado) { 
    System.out.println("archivo copiado");
}
```

Con respecto a las fechas de creación, [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html) en la documentación, dice que el único atributo que funciona en todas las plataformas es la fecha de modificación. Con respecto a la fecha de creación, dependerá de la plataforma.

Si fuera sobre windows, [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3350512/2573335) tienes una clase que permite cambiar la fecha de creación. Pero ten cuidado, como ha mencionado @LuiggiMendoza utiliza paquetes de `com.sun` que dependen de la implementación de la JVM.

Comment: Yo diría que se tenga cuidado con esa clase para windows porque utiliza clases com.sun que no deben ser utilizadas directamente puesto que dependen de la implementación de la jvm

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza buena aclaración lo añadiré a la respuesta.

Comment: La parte de `StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES` fue la que me sirvió, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

> `Files.copy` debe ser la respuesta aceptada, ya que tiene un mejor rendimiento que otras opciones, pero solo esta disponible para Java 7 +

Para Java 6, puede usar el siguiente metodo:

```
public void copy(File original, File destino) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(original);
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destino);
        try {

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

O utilizar [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) de [Apache Commons](https://commons.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Desde Java 7 puede usar la clase `Files` de su API llamada *New Input Output* Formalemnte `NIO`.

```
 Files.copy( from.toPath(), to.toPath() );
```

También puede especificar opciones de copiado como tercer parámetro.

Más información: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html